# Progressing from a single neuron to two in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I found learning neural networks through the [simplest possible example](https://medium.com/technology-invention-and-more/how-to-build-a-simple-neural-network-in-9-lines-of-python-code-cc8f23647ca1) to be a great way to start. The basic workings are very understandable when you narrow it down like this.

I thought the smallest possible next step would be to still have only one hidden layer, but increase the number of neurons in the hidden layer from one to two, and then some questions arise:

1. What specific benefit do I get from going from a single neurons to two (for a simple task)?
2. Why are different neurons initialised with different random weights? Does it mean you start multiple journeys in n-dimensional landscape to increase chance of finding global minimum?
3. Why does one send signals from *all* the nodes in one layer to *all* the nodes in the next layer? All figures I've seen show the same many-to-many arrows, but none explain *why*!

I've read many introduction articles on the topic, but I couldn't find any that cover these questions.

Answer (score 0):

With a single output neuron you can only make a binary classification. When you put multiple neurons in the output layer, you can define a more complex classification problem. The common case is to do a [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) encoding for N classes where your have N neurons in the output layer and each of those neurons corresponds to a distinct class. The output for class `i` would have zeros for all the output neurons except output `i`, which would be equal to one.

Randomizing with different weights isn't strictly required but can speed up training of the network. Since you typically want each neuron in a given layer to converge to a distinct decision boundary, it helps to start them out with different random weights because they will diverge faster.

There is no strict requirement that all the neurons in one layer of a general ANN connect to all the neurons in adjacent layers (i.e., a fully-connected layer). One of the benefits of doing so is that you can more easily compute network outputs via matrix multiplication and backpropagation is simpler as well. Having the layers fully-connect allows the network to produce more complex decision surfaces. Removing some of the connections from a layer is effectively the same as fixing the corresponding weight to zero.

Comment: The first paragraph was quite clarifying. The second and third, I still don't understand specifically how the nodes co-operate when signals are sent many-to-many. Or can't this be easily understood specifically (like with the simple example of one neuron), only on a more abstract level without understanding the inner workings, and you just have to trust these techniques have been found to return good results?

Comment: Each neuron makes a binary (or approximately binary) decision based on its weighted inputs. In that sense, each neuron in a fully connected network functions just like the single neuron case. The difference is that the hidden layer neurons are making decisions based on other decisions (the outputs from the previous layer). When you train the network, each neuron learns which inputs (outputs from previous layer neurons) it should care about and how to combine them into a decision. One typically only needs to understand the "inner workings" in general for designing the network architecture.